# azure run command script to mount file storage

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, file-storage, runcommand

I have created VM which needs to download some files from Azure File Storage. I am looking for a way to automate this and I am trying the Azure VM Run command Script.

The first step CmdKey is all working fine but the next step which is:

```
net use Z: \\my123storageaccount.file.core.windows.net\databases /u:AZURE\my123storageaccount sskhgkghgkuytiytru...==
```

is failing [with these messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FvZQ.png).

When I login to that VM and run the command in PowerShell window it works without any error.

One thing that might help is the storage account name in the error is trimming the first letter the one I have. For instance, if it's called MyStorageAccount in the error it is saying yStorageAccount.file.core.windows.net

any help

Comment: What is the failing error?

Comment: How are the things going on your side? Has this Issue been resolved?

Comment: Is there any update in this case?

Comment: According to the docs, "Scripts run as System on Windows." Maybe the user you're logging in as to use the files does have the same credentials.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was that, according to the [Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command), "scripts run as System on Windows." So when you login as your normal user, that user doesn't have the credentials saved, and can't view the mounted drive contents.

To workaround this, you can use `psexec` (from the [`PSTools` package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools)) to run as your regular user. For example:

```
psexec.exe \\your-ip -u your-user -p your-pass cmdkey /add:...
psexec.exe \\your-ip -u your-user -p your-pass net use Z: \my123storageaccount.file.core.windows.net\databases /u:AZURE\my123storageaccount sskhgkghgkuytiytru...==
```

Note: Due to [voodoo black magic](http://www.brandonmartinez.com/2013/04/24/resolve-access-is-denied-using-psexec-with-a-local-admin-account/), you have to use the form of `psexec.exe \\your-ip` rather than just `psexec.exe` as System user, or risk upsetting Billy Goates.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy files like this. The powershell commands can be copied from Azure, using 'connect' from the context menu of the share in the Azure portal. If this doesn't work could be connectivity or may be SMB related

```
$buildSource = 'M:\build\'

$acctKey = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 
"Azure\wserverBuild", $acctKey
New-PSDrive -Name M -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\wserverBuild.file.core.windows.net\build" -Credential $credential -Persist

Copy-Item  'M:\build\' -Destination 'C:build' -Recurse
```

Comment: Hi Tim
I am g4tting this
New-PSDrive -Name M -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\mystorageaccount.file.core.windows.net\databases" -Credential $credential 
New-PSDrive : Illegal characters in path.

Comment: it's possible you have have spurious characters in your code. If you use the cut paste method from the portal it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Update

On my side, I can download some files from Azure File Storage with Azure VM run command script.

The main steps are as follows:

- Copy the script from my storage account-files-connect.
- Paste the script to Azure virtual machine-run command-RunPowerShellScript-PowerShellScript.

[image]

According to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command#limiting-access-to-run-command), Running a command requires the `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/runCommand/action` permission, which the Contributor role and higher have. Please check this one your side.

Also, check the Azure VM Agent when logging into the Azure VM, look for a process name WindowsAzureGuestAgent.exe from Task Manager.

References: [Azure Virtual Machine Agent overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/agent-windows)

Comment: I found the script from storage account and it works if I RDP to the VM but it doesn't work when I try it in **Run Command Script**.

Comment: I also use this script from the portal, and can you share your Run Command Script?

Comment: @MohsenKokabi Any update? Could you restart your VM or update the VM agent on your side?

Answer (score 0):

if you go to the storage account -> files you can copy the powershell commands you need to map the drive.

[image]

Comment: Thank Nancy, yes this is where I get the command and it works when I RDP to the VM but if I try it in **Run Command Script** it gives error.